# How do I use a USB OTG cable to read a USB thumbdrive on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, usb

Is is possible to use a USB OTG (On-The-Go) cable hooked to the Arduino Uno's (or similar) USB connector to read a thumb drive or other device?  If it is possible, what software would be needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not without getting your hands dirty or buying a shield.

Arduinos are configured by default as slave usb devices. Slave devices cannot connect to other slave devices, so connecting a thumb drive via a USB OTG cable is meaningless.

If you don't want to get your hands dirty, there is the [USB host shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9628) as suggested by @Kevin which should work.

If you *do* want to get your hands dirty, you can try [flashing new firmware on the 8u2/16u2 chip](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) on the Uno. This chip is what gives the main ATmega328 the ability to load programs and send serial output via USB. It can be reprogrammed to be various things: a joystick, a mouse, a keyboard.

However, it is not limited to slave devices, one can also program it to be a host. With a Due, being a [USB Host](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost) for a mouse or keyboard is quite easy, but for other Arduinos you need to program the 8u2/16u2 chip.

Note that programming an Arduino to understand a USB mass storage device has not been done yet. There will be a significant amount of mucking through code if you wish to do this.

Basically, you use the [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) library, specifically the [USB Mass Storage Host](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/130303/html/group___group___u_s_b_class_mass_storage_host.html) class. I can't find *anything* apart from that doc page and the source code of the class (which is extensive), so I can't write up the code myself. However, you may want to take a look at [this tutorial on making an Arduino joystick via LUFA](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,111.0.html) to get started.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly what you described but I'd look into the [USB Host Shield](http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-2-0-for-arduino). There's a [fully assembled version](http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-2-0-for-arduino-assembled/) for $5 more.  It comes with [an awesome, actively developed set of libraries](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) that easily allow you to control a variety of devices (PS3/Xbox/Wii controller, and more)  with nice APIs. It provides you with everything you'll need to get up and running quickly with USB. There's a [generic_storage](https://github.com/xxxajk/generic_storage) lib that may help with reading/writing to flash drives.

I've used it to communicate with a PlayStation 3 controller by plugging in a Bluetooth dongle with great success.